# How to use event.value in React-Native

Tags: react-native

The event doesn't work in React-Native.
This is textInput.

```
      <TextInput
          id="name"
          placeholder="name"
          onChange = {this._inputChange}

            />
```

And This is the onChage function.
when i check with console.log(e.nativeEvent.id) writing in TextInput, it says undefined.
I guess that e.target.id can't use in React-native not React.
Could you recommend some idea?

```
_inputChange = (e) => {
    let nextState = {};
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.id)
    nextState[e.nativeEvent.id] = e.nativeEvent.value;
    this.setState(nextState);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handle this...

```
handleChange = (field, value) ={
  this.setState({ [field]: value });
}

<TextInput
  onChangeText={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}
  ...
  />
```